# Rayleigh quotient problem

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and that 
 $\mathbf{Av}=\lambda \mathbf{v}$  with $\|\mathbf{v}\|=1$. Show that 
 if $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ approximates the eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ in the 
 sense that $\mathbf{x}=\alpha\mathbf{v}+\varepsilon \mathbf{y}$ for 
 $\alpha\neq 0$ and some 
 $\mathbf{y}\perp \mathbf{v}$ with $\|\mathbf{y}\|=1$, then the Rayleigh quotients for 
 $\mathbf{x}$ satisfy
 $$
 \frac{\mathbf{x}^{*}\mathbf{Ax}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2}}=\lambda + 
 \mathcal{O} \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\alpha}\right)
$$
and if $\mathbf{A}$ is Hermitian, then
$$
 \frac{\mathbf{x}^{*}\mathbf{Ax}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2}}=\lambda + 
 \mathcal{O} \left(\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\alpha}\right)^{2} \right)
$$
Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: This really is mostly a matter of grinding through the computations. Note that $\|x\|^2 = |\alpha|^1 + |\epsilon|^2$. Remember that $\alpha $ is fixed.

Comment: @copper.hat can you give more details please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\|x\|^2 = |\alpha|^2 + |\epsilon|^2$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle x , Ax \rangle &=& \langle \alpha v + \epsilon y , A(\alpha v + \epsilon y ) \rangle \\
&=& \langle \alpha v + \epsilon y ,\alpha \lambda v + \epsilon Ay \rangle \\
&=&  |\alpha|^2\lambda + \overline{\alpha} \epsilon \langle v , Ay \rangle  + |\epsilon|^2 \langle y , Ay \rangle
\end{eqnarray}
and so
\begin{eqnarray}
{ \langle x , Ax \rangle \over \|x\|^2 } &=& { \langle x , Ax \rangle \over  |\alpha|^2 + |\epsilon|^2} \\
&=&\lambda  - { |\epsilon|^2 \over  |\alpha|^2 + |\epsilon|^2 }\lambda + { \overline{\alpha} \epsilon\langle v , Ay \rangle \over  |\alpha|^2 + |\epsilon|^2 } + { |\epsilon|^2 \langle y , Ay \rangle \over  |\alpha|^2 + |\epsilon|^2 } \\
&=& \lambda  - { |{ \epsilon \over \alpha } |^2 \over  1 + |{ \epsilon \over \alpha }|^2 }\lambda + { {\overline{\alpha} \over \alpha}  {\epsilon \over \alpha }\langle v , Ay \rangle \over 1 + |{ \epsilon \over \alpha }|^2 } + { |{ \epsilon \over \alpha }|^2 \langle y , Ay \rangle \over  1 + |{ \epsilon \over \alpha }|^2 } \\
\end{eqnarray}
from which the first result follows.

The second result follows from expanding $\langle v , Ay \rangle$.